# How to add facebook comment plugin in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, gatsby

I'm creating a blog site using Gatsby. I am very very new to Gatsby/React. I need some documentation about the facebook comment plugin for Gatsby.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm interested in the same question. I was looking and found only the plugin that @prestonso mentions. However it doesn't provide comments functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean retrieving Facebook comments using Facebook's Graph API, which provides [comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/comment), you may be able to achieve that with [`gatsby-source-facebook`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-facebook/), which you can install as follows into your Gatsby site:

```
npm install --save gatsby-source-facebook
```

Then, configure the source plugin by adding this to `gatsby-config.js`:

```
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-facebook`,
      options: {
        places: [`${facebookPageID}`], // Can be either a numeric ID or the URL ID
        params: {
          fields: 'hours, posts { message, created_time }', // See Facebooks API to see what you can query for
        },
        key: process.env.FACEBOOK_GRAPH_TOKEN, // You will need to create a Facebook application and go through review in order to get an API token.
      },
    },
  ],
```

When you execute `gatsby develop` and navigate to the provisioned local environment, such as `http://localhost:8000`, you should be able to explore your GraphQL schema using GraphiQL at `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [onRenderBody](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#onRenderBody) function from the `Gatsby's SSR (Server Side Rendering) APIs`. In your `gatsby-ssr.js` file paste the following code

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's SSR (Server Side Rendering) APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/
 */


const React = require("react")

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setPostBodyComponents([
    <div id="fb-root"></div>,
    <script
      async
      defer
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      src="https://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&autoLogAppEvents=1&version=v9.0&appId=*you app id*"
      nonce="rlVIHZ6h"
    ></script>,
  ])
}
```

And than you will render the comments in your article or wherever you want with the rest of the code

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://yourwebsite.com/blog/*" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm i react-facebook`

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { FacebookProvider, Comments } from 'react-facebook';
 
export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookProvider appId="123456789">
        <Comments href="http://www.facebook.com" />
      </FacebookProvider>
    );
  }
}
```