# I want to display articles using gatsby-source-facebook

Tags: facebook, gatsby

I want to display the data of an article using gatsby-source-facebook.
But I don't know how to write a query.
I can't find the best query at http://localhost:8000/___graphql

I make a simple website with `gatsby.js`.
I want to get facebook article data (posting date and text) and display it on the site.
I installed `gatsby-source-facebook` for that.
And changed `gatsby-config.js`. 
→ https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-facebook/

```
//`gatsby-config.js`

plugins: [
    {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-facebook`,
        options: {
        places: [`${facebookPageID}`], // Can be either a numeric ID or the URL ID
        params: {
          fields: 'hours, posts { message, created_time }', // See Facebooks API to see what you can query for
        },
        key: process.env.FACEBOOK_GRAPH_TOKEN, // You will need to create a Facebook application and go through review in order to get an API token.
        },
    },
],
```

I don't know how to write a query, so I can't get the data. (Can not be displayed.)
For example, http://localhost:8000/___graphql

```
query {
    site {
        siteMetadata {
            title
            description
        }
    }
}
```

If you enter and execute}, the title and description of the site set in `gatsby-config.js` enter code here will be displayed. This is normal. So how do you write a query to display facebook article data?

I searched a lot to solve this problem, but I didn't find a solution.
I only found a similar question ([How to add facebook comment plugin in Gatsby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554574/how-to-add-facebook-comment-plugin-in-gatsby)) but it could not be resolved. This question was the same as what I wrote here (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-facebook/).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr:

Try this:

```
query {
  allFacebookArticles {
    edges {
      node {
        title,
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Explanation

[That plugin stores its data into types matching the format `Facebook${type}`](https://gitlab.com/kada-development/gatsby-source-facebook/blob/master/src/gatsby-node.ts#L60) where `$type` is the type of thing you're pulling (in your case, articles, so it'd be `FacebookArticle`).

From GraphiQL, though, you should be able to see that on the sidebar on the left.

Here's an example from my current project (with some other options open):

[image: GraphiQL screen]

Comment: thank you for your comment.
I have completed the settings here (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-facebook/).
However, allFacebookArticles is not displayed in the left sidebar of GraphiQL.
Are there any necessary settings?
What is the cause?

Comment: You may want to check the logs when building the site to see if there were any errors; otherwise I would use the Facebook dev tools to make sure your key is good.