# How to use gatsby-source-facebook to pull posts

Tags: gatsby

I'm working in Gatsby and for the first time ever I'm trying to get the Facebook posts of a groups page to show on my site. I already created a facebook application in using the **facebook for developers dashboard**. Now I installed the **gatsby-source-facebook** plugin, but I'm not sure of how to use it. So far I did the following, here's the code.

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-facebook`,
      options: {
        places: [`${facebookPageID}`], // Can be either a numeric ID or the URL ID
        params: {
          fields: 'hours, posts { message, created_time }', // See Facebooks API to see what you can query for
        },
        key: process.env.FACEBOOK_GRAPH_TOKEN, // You will need to create a Facebook application and go through review in order to get an API token.
        version: '5.0', // The version of the graph API to use. Defaults to 5.0
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

I already plug the **facebookPageID**, but for the `params{fields:???}`, I'm not sure what's the proper way to describe this part.

For the `key:`, I have created a token key but I don't know if I have to enter it there...

I've tried providing all the data to this configuration but when I started the server I got this error:

```
     ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-source-facebook" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

[object Object]

warn The gatsby-source-facebook plugin has generated no Gatsby nodes. Do you need it?
```

I found a post here on stackoverflow that is very similar to my problem but I still have some doubts, [I want to display articles using gatsby-source-facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753265/i-want-to-display-articles-using-gatsby-source-facebook)

Can someone please give me a better clue of how to do these steps? I searched in many different places but I don't get many clear answers on this topic.

Thanks.